# How to make UITabbarcontroller show over all other view controllers?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I want the tabs at the bottom to always show, even when I present a modal view contoller. So when I call
[self presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];
It shouldn't display over the tab bar, but underneath it (This would result in the lower part of the view controller being hidden by the tab bar controller, which is what I want)
How would I do this??

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the way to do it, you simply have to set the view controller view as your own.
So you would say:
Receipt b = [[Receipt alloc]init];
[self setView:b.view];